# Creating .eps file with spplot in R

Tags: r, plot, adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to create high resolution figures from maps I created in R. Whenever I try creating an .eps file with spplot it creates a relatively large file (~13,040 KB) that I cannot open with Adobe Illustrator. Here is an example of something I've tried that produced such a file:

```
postscript("60plot789.eps",horizontal = TRUE, onefile = TRUE, paper = 
           "special")
 print(spplot(mi.ok.15.7[c('pred15.9','pred18.9','pred24.9','pred36.9','pred48.9','pred72.9',
                 'pred15.8','pred18.8','pred24.8','pred36.8','pred48.8','pred72.8',
                 'pred15.7','pred18.7','pred24.7','pred36.7','pred48.7','pred72.7')],
    col.regions=RHCols(20), sp.layout=list(pts, border), names.attr=names789,
    par.strip.text = list(cex = 0.75),
    scales=list(draw = FALSE), layout=(mat),
    main=paste("RH OK Results (60% RH): 15,18,24,36, 48, 72 hours, Biweeks 7,8,9"),
    colorkey = list(at = c(0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70,75,80,85,90,95,100), 
                    labels = list( at =  c(0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100),
                                   labels = c('0','10','20','30','40','50','60','70','80','90','100')
                    ))))
dev.off()
```

Is there a way I can create .eps files using spplot that can be opened in Adobe Illustrator? Or would it be better to use a different file type for high resolution images? (300, 600 dpi)?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried opening the EPS in Photoshop? Illustrator is meant to work with vector images (bezier curves), while it has some limited capabilities to deal with pixels, it's the wrong tool.

Comment: Using Photoshop worked better, thank you for the suggestion!